# Speed up the calculation of a new feature (a cycle about rows for a time and object)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with cars and their prices, where each row contains the price for which it was sold and the time of sale. I want to create a new feature that for each row will show the amount of sales for this car for the last 2 hours, multiplied by 0.2.

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for car in pd.unique(df['car_id']):
    
    car_rows = df[df['car_id'] == car]
    
    sum_cars = []
    for row in car_rows.itertuples():
        rows = car_rows[(car_rows['time'] < row.time) & (car_rows['time'] > row.time - pd.Timedelta(hours=2))]
        if rows.shape[0] == 0:
            sum_cars.append(0)
            continue

        sum_cars.append(np.sum(rows.apply(lambda x: 0.2 * x.price, axis=1)))

    car_rows['sum_cars'] = sum_cars
    res = pd.concat([res, car_rows])
```

This code is very slow (500k rows in 30 minutes). Any ideas for speeding up?

Example (calculating feature sum_cars):

```
car_id  time               price    sum_cars
    1   2019-01-02 16:55:13  10    0.0
    1   2019-01-02 16:59:37  20    2.0
    1   2019-01-02 17:35:18  30    6.0
    2   2019-01-03 17:45:13  40    0.0
    2   2019-01-03 18:35:13  50    8.0
    2   2019-01-03 20:55:13  60    0.0
    2   2019-01-03 21:54:13  70    12.0
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It is likely that the answer would be immediate to many of us if we could see an example input-desired output. I don't enjoy trying to imagine what the input might be just based on someone's code.

Comment: @PierreD  I added example, can you see please?

Comment: Please provide an example of _input_ dataframe in a form that is easy to copy/paste, along with some _desired_ result. Note: please don't paste images of code or data.

Comment: yes done, is that better?

Comment: almost... it would be good to provide some minimal input as well. But I'm going to read between the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very useful construct in `pandas` called "Rolling GroupBy" (`pandas.core.window.rolling.RollingGroupby`, obtained by `df.groupby(...).rolling(...)`).

With some synthetic data containing 500K rows, I see execution times of about 135ms (a speedup of over 13,000x). (**Note**: this is using `pandas=1.2.1`; a friend who was still using `pandas=1.1.4` was observing times 35x slower than what I'm reporting here -- a good reminder to update regularly).

The quantity that you want to compute is:

```py
>>> z = df.groupby('car_id').rolling(
...     '2H', closed='left', min_periods=0)['price'].sum() * 0.2
>>> z
car_id  time               
1       2019-01-02 16:55:13     0.0
        2019-01-02 16:59:37     2.0
        2019-01-02 17:35:18     6.0
2       2019-01-03 17:45:13     0.0
        2019-01-03 18:35:13     8.0
        2019-01-03 20:55:13     0.0
        2019-01-03 21:54:13    12.0
```

Now, the trick is to re-arrange `df` so that its index is `(car_id, time)` (we sort it too). Then we can assign the calculated quantity `z` to a new column `sum_cars`:

```py
out = df.set_index(
    'car_id', append=True).swaplevel().sort_index().assign(sum_cars=z)
```

Now:

```py
>>> out
                            price  sum_cars
car_id time                                
1      2019-01-02 16:55:13     10       0.0
       2019-01-02 16:59:37     20       2.0
       2019-01-02 17:35:18     30       6.0
2      2019-01-03 17:45:13     40       0.0
       2019-01-03 18:35:13     50       8.0
       2019-01-03 20:55:13     60       0.0
       2019-01-03 21:54:13     70      12.0
```

### Speed

```py
def gen_data(n=10):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'car_id': np.random.randint(0, 3, n),
        'price': np.random.normal(10, 5, n).round(),
        'time': pd.Series(
            pd.Timestamp('2019-01-02') + np.random.uniform(0, 5, n)
            * pd.Timedelta('1H')).dt.floor('s'),
    }).set_index('time').sort_index()
    return df

def func(df):
    z = df.groupby('car_id').rolling(
        '2H', closed='left', min_periods=0)['price'].sum() * 0.2
    return (
        df.set_index('car_id', append=True).swaplevel().sort_index()
        .assign(sum_cars=z)
    )

df = gen_data(500_000)
%timeit func(df)
# 135 ms ± 173 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: looks great, but how can  make  that the first line for the car_id is always zero (that is, a shift where first value = 0) ?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand?  `car_id` is whatever you have as car IDs. You could have strings too, or int IDs starting at some arbitrary value. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean values for a new function, for example, for a car_id = 1 from my example, I want sum_cars = [0,2,6], but your script returns [2,6,12]

Comment: I see. Just updated to use `closed='left', min_periods=0` in the `rolling()`.